# How to search a passage of text using a dictionary as reference

Tags: database, search, sentence

I would like to create a database of words, where the word and part of speech is listed. Then, for simple examples, I would like to search a passage of text and identify the words' parts of speech based on the database.

Comment: So are you saying you have different sayings in a database e.g. "fit as a fiddle" and you want to find this in a paragraph you provide from somewhere? Are you doing this in code or mysql? Do you want a query or code? A little more information is required.

Comment: I know MySQL would probably be involved, and I wanted the code for the  program, and an idea of how to link the code and the database together. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, and everything you said previously is true.

Answer (score 1):

Then it's simple. Create a table in your database called 'phrases' or something to that affect. Load the table into memory - in an array or something. Then cycle through each one doing a string compare or contains with your paragraph ... depending on what language you are using.

It's a little hard to give you any more information if you don't even say what language you are using.